# A basis for induction - What is the point of this argument?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I came across an argument in a book, and I'm wondering why we need this proof.

Let $T \subset \mathbb{N}$ where:

1. $0 \in T$
2. If $n-1 \in T$ then $n \in T$

Let $A = \mathbb{N}\backslash T$, we claim that $A$ is the empty set.

We argue by contradiction. Let $A = \mathbb{N}\backslash T$ and assume $A$ is non-empty. By the well ordering principle, there exists a least element, $s \in A$ for which $s < a$ for all $a \in A$, $a \neq s$. If $s \in A$ then $s-1 \notin A$ since $s-1 < s$, and $s$ was the least element of $A$. If $s-1 \notin A$ then $s-1 \in T$. If $s-1 \in T$ then, by axiom 2, $s \in T$. This is a contradiction because $s$ can't be in both $A$ and $T$ since $A=\mathbb{N}\backslash T$. It follows that $A$ is empty.

I would have thought that the first two axioms could be used to define $\mathbb{N}$, and that $A=\mathbb{N}\backslash T$ would obviously be empty. **Could someone please explain the necessity of this proof?** I believe it is needed to show that mathematical induction is valid, but seems like a tautology to me.

Comment: You are asuming the well ordering principle to prove induction.

Comment: It should be $T\subseteq\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @fvel Why? Except for typography the two are the same.

Comment: @fvel Not necessarily. The symbol $\subset$ does not mean a proper subset, $\subsetneq$ does.

Comment: @DiegoRobayo That's the point: why do I have to prove induction? For me, the first two axioms generate the natural numbers and that's why induction works.

Comment: There are more sets that satisfy the first two axioms. $\mathbb Z$ for instance. The axioms are used, but are not enough.

Comment: The start is: "Let $T\subset\mathbb N$". That only makes sense if $\mathbb N$ is allready defined.

Comment: @FlybyNight because you are asuming the well ordering principle, and with it you are proving that $T = \mathbb{N}$. I understand what you say that $T = \mathbb{N}$ it is pretty much straight forward, but it is because you are asuming the well ordering principle, try to prove it with the same construction of $T$ but without the well ordering principle.

Comment: @drhab This isn't my proof, so don't shoot the messenger. Even though the axioms could generate both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, I could still use mathematical induction to prove statement for all $\mathbb{N}$ and all $\mathbb{Z}$. For the induction step I would need to prove that $T(k) \implies T(k+1)$ and $T(k) \implies T(k-1)$. I still don't see why I need to prove this to justify using mathematical induction.

Comment: It is indeed necessary, because with it you show that the well ordering principle implies induction. And that is "one side" of saying that those two (induction and well ordering) are equivalent.

Comment: @DiegoRobayo I agree that I can't prove it without the WOP. My original point is *why do I have to prove it at all?*

Comment: @FlybyNight, I think that depends a lot on what you are studying and/or doing.

Answer (score 1):

One can go either way. If you start by assuming the well-ordering principle, then you prove the principle of induction in this way. Conversely, if you start, as you suggest, by assuming the principle of induction, then you can prove the well-orderedness of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus it's inefficient to assume both, so that people pick one to take as evident and prove the other from it.

Comment: I still don't understand *why* we need this proof. Surely induction works because the first two axioms generate all of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But how do you know that?

Comment: Because that's the definition of the natural numbers:
$$\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$$
Some people leave out $0$.

Comment: What you've written down is not a definition. Your ellipsis conceals the implicit assumption that it's clear what it means to iterate the successor operation indefinitely, which is exactly what the notion of induction is meant to clarify. In fact the most obvious attempts to precisely define the natural numbers don't uniquely specify $\mathbb{N}$ at all! "The" definition, to the extent such a thing exists, is the Peano axioms, one of which asserts that $\mathbb{N}$ admits induction.

Comment: I appreciate your patience here, but I'm still not seeing it. For me, the axioms "$0 \in \mathbb{N}$" and "If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$" seem to generate what I know as the natural numbers. I would take that as my formal definition. Mathematical inductions works for that same reason. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your formal definition includes mathematical induction, although you should say $x\in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if there's $y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=y+1$ for completeness. So from your definition one can prove well-orderedness. It's also possible to define the natural numbers as a well-ordered set with various other properties without assuming induction holds, and then to prove induction. Basically, your definition assumes induction and that's not the only possibility.

Comment: One thing to take away from this proof is that given *any* well ordered set, induction holds. Nothing specific about *your* definition of $\mathbb N$ was used in the proof.  This truth is independent of the way you've chosen to define $\mathbb N$